# Validating wifi password between router and client

Tags: wireless-networking

How work validating WiFi password, how computer knows what is correct password. Has computer send data to router, and then router validating and give feedback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When comparing passwords from one place to the other, it is often done as follows:

Computer encrypts the password using a high encryption algorithm. When you transmit your password, it is also encrypted using the same method. Then the encrypted version is sent to the target and it is being compared to whatever it is on the target side. This means the password does not have to be compared in plain text to known to be valid, and as such it cannot be decrypted.

Lets assume you go to the router and set password: `hello`. The router encrypts it to: `$1%7AvEsGerxBrHhbrdbRVaW3Ts` and stores this in its internal database.

Now, you enter a password. Your computer encrypts this and the result is: `$1%7AvEdSGeBerEfSgERDgRwETa` and transmits that to the router.

The router then compares `$1%7AvEsGerxBrHhbrdbRVaW3Ts` to `$1%7AvEdSGeBerEfSgERDgRwETa` and finds out the hashes do not match. As such, the passwords do not match. But not once did the password be sent. If the right password is entered, it is encoded to the right hash, and the router has 2 identical hashes, and thus, the password matches. If it does, the router grants permission to use the wifi capabilities and communication starts.